# See Network Tab In React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-debugger

I just started a new app in Expo after my RN CLI app was wiped out from a Xcode update (still scarred/confused on what exactly happened).

In CLI I was able to use the [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) tool without issue. On Expo, I have not been able to get it working.

I followed the directions in [issue](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/754#issuecomment-1469852938)

```
// Add to app.json

"jsEngine": "hermes",
"ios": {
   "jsEngine": "jsc",
   "supportsTablet": true
}
```

This did not work. I tried getting rid of the `ios` object so that my `jsEngine` is `hermes` but this also didn't work.

Steps:

1. Start a new Expo project using `npx expo start --localhost`
2. Set `"jsEngine": "hermes"` in `app.json`
3. Wait for app to turn on
4. Run `open "rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=19000"`

I get the debugger UI open, but it does not connect to my app.

My app is running Expo 48.x.x. Is my only option to downgrade to Expo <47? Not being able to see my network requests is unbearable and very surprised that this is not an out of the box feature in RN yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expo SDK 49 now has built-in Network debugging, but unfortunately it does not work correctly on Android at this time. More info below.

To get notified when it's fixed, subscribe to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/38006#issuecomment-1612231371)

> Important: Due to a regression in the Hermes debugger for Android in React Native 0.72 (see GitHub for context), we recommend waiting before upgrading to SDK 49 if this is an important part of your workflow. Additionally, in order to ensure that new projects default to a working debugging experience, the default project created by create-expo-app will continue to be set to SDK 48 until this issue is resolved.
>
> To create a new project with SDK 49: `npx create-expo-app@latest --template blank@sdk-49` Replace “blank” with “tabs” for the expo-router template.

via [Expo SDK 49](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-49-c6d398cdf740)